# Проблема с OnClickListener В GridView во время скролла Android

Tags: android, прокрутка, adapter, gridview

Имеется GridView к которому подключен адаптер.
Данные в GridView заносятся нормально.
Проблема в следующем:
Когда я обрабатываю событие OnItemClickListener в GridView, то подсвечивается выделенная строка. Однако когда я делаю скролл GridView, то каким то образом индексы элементов сбиваются, и элемент на который я нажимаю не подсвечивается, а подсвечивается элемент ниже его (в зависимости от того, как далеко я прокрутил GridView). Когда я возвращаю скролл в первоначальную позицию то строка выделяется как нужно.

**Скриншоты для лучшего понимания:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее я делаю скролл на одну позицию вниз, и выюираю ту же строку что на первом скрине, однако выделяется строка ниже неё
 Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код адаптера, и метода нажатия на GridView:

Адаптер

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Cat cat = getItem(position);
    String s = cat.Uch;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,null);
    }
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tt)).setText(cat.Hour);
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tt1)).setText(cat.Uch);
    if(s.startsWith("Свободно"))
        ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(lay)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect1);
    else
        ((LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(lay)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect);
    return convertView;
}
```

Метод нажатия

```
gvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            if (gvmaincl==0) {
                fab1.startAnimation(animationbut);
                fab1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               fab2.startAnimation(animationbut);
               fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (v1!=null) {
                l = (LinearLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.lay);
                if (Objects.equals(t1.getText().toString(), "Свободно"))
                    l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect1);
                else
                    l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect);
            }

            v1 = gvMain.getChildAt(position);
            l = (LinearLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.lay);
            t = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.tt);
            t1 = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.tt1);
            l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect2);
}
    });
```

Подскажите в чем проблема, и как её можно исправить.

Comment: А какие значения у всех этих загадочных букв v1, t1 перед входом в слушатель? метод `findViewById()` очень ресурсозатратный, чтобы дергать их при каждом нажатии. Получите ссылки на виджеты один раз при создании интерфейса (в `onCreate()`) и присвойте их полям класса, затем обращайтесь к этим полям, а не ищите каждый раз по новой одно и то же.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос (я только осваиваюсь в программировании под Android), а к какому классу присвоить созданные в OnCreate ссылки?

Comment: И каким образом мне тогда находить View нажатого элемента в GridView?

Comment: найдите в себе силы прочитать пару книжек: Эккеля "Философия Java" и Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" и не придется ссылаться на недостаток знаний в таких элементарных вопросах, это база. Сейчас вы делаете следующее: чтобы позвонить другу, с которым вы созваниваетесь несколько раз в день, вы каждый раз звоните в справочную, объясняете там, кто вам нужен, ждете некоторое время когда его найдут и скажут телефон, потом его набираете и говорите с другом - выглядит весьма нелепо, но именно так вы используете метод findViewById() сейчас.

Comment: Вместо этого логичнее один раз записать телефон себе и потом сразу по нему звонить, когда понадобится - при создании UI активити, ссылки на виджеты сохранить в поля класса этой активити и дальше работать с ними. В адаптере для этих же целей используется паттерн ViewHolder.

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение, возьму книжки на заметку. Метод ViewHolder действительно позволяет решить мою проблему, буду разбираться. Еще раз спасибо